# Android:Virtual machine cannot download file from website

Tags: android

I have written an app to download a **.PDF** file from the given url path.
But when I run it in the vm,I found my app cannot download the file.
So I tryed the **DownloadManager** in the vm,still it cannot download the file .
And the DownloadManage stopped with just and always showing "*OnGoing*".
Can anyone tell me the reason and how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance! 
**PS:I write this**

```
public File writeFileToSDCard(String path,String fileName,InputStream in){
    File file = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try{
        if(!createDir(path)){
            Log.e("FileUtils.java", "writeFileToSDCard().createDir() failed!");
        }else{
            Log.e("FileUtils.java", "writeFileToSDCard().createDir() Successed!");
        }
        file = createFile(path+fileName);
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte buffer[] = new byte[128];
        //write the file
        do{
            int length = in.read(buffer);
            if(length != -1){
                Log.e("FileUtils.java", "Writing to card!");
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }while(true);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("FileUtils.java", "writeFileToSDCard() failed!");
    }finally {
        try{
            out.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("FileUtils.java", "writeFileToSDCard() finally failed!");
        }
    }
    return file;
}
```

**PSS:**I dont think my code goes wrong,but Is it the problem of the android emulator?

Comment: Please post your code for downloading and the url to the file you are trying to download.

Comment: By vm, do you mean the android emulator? Have you tried downloading the file from an actual device?

Comment: @Zhao Have you tried downloading from a real device?

Comment: @Aki nope.Is it because the emulator cannot download file from web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it is because you don't have permission to download the file from the server.

I had a similar problem few days back, I solved it by creating a **.htacces** file in the server directory. Create a file named **.htacess** containing this :

```
satisfy any
```

and save it in the directory where your pdf file is. I am not familiar with how this works, but I guess it has something to do with the permissions. Note that if you do this anyone can access the contents of that directory. And I believe this will only wirk for Apache servers.

Don't know if it will work, but its worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But the PDF file is located in the website and I cannot write a .htacess file and put it into the its server.Thanks all the same:-)